# Creating an array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I have 2 arrays:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
const array2 = [{a: 23, b: 22, c: 14}, {a: 78, b: 22, c: 14}, {id: 3, a: 23, b: 80, c: 14}]
```

And I need update array1 according to the following conditions:
for each element from the array I need to return an object:

```
[{name: 'a', isDifferent: true}, {name: 'b', isDifferent: true}, {name: 'c', isDifferent: false}]
```

where isDifferent is true, for a given name, at least one value differs.

This is my function. It works.
But I think there are easier ways to do this.

```
array1 = array1.map(el => {
 const newObj = {}
 newObj.name = el
 let isDifferent = false
 for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  if (array2[i][el] !== array2[0][el]) {
    isDifferent = true
    break
  }
 }
 newObj.isDifferent = isDifferent
 return newObj
})
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me - can you be more specific on an "easier" way? Are you having performance issues?

Comment: sidenote you should not define  variable with const if its going to change, since its an mutable data type its not throwing any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method :

```js
const array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
const array2 = [{a: 23, b: 22, c: 14}, {a: 78, b: 22, c: 14}, {id: 3, a: 23, b: 80, c: 14}]

let result = array1.map( letter => {
 let values = array2.map(obj => obj[letter]); // Getting [23, 78, 3] for "a"
 return {
  name : letter,
  isDifferent : !values.every(v => v===values[0]) // Checks if every value in the array equals the first one
 }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can take a look at javascript `reduce` array method.
[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array2 = [{a: 23, b: 22, c: 14}, {a: 78, b: 22, c: 14}, {id: 3, a: 23, b: 80, c: 14}]

const arr = array2.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
     acc.push(curr.forEach(()=>{}))
},[])
```

Comment: Your code yields `Uncaught TypeError: curr.forEach is not a function`

Comment: It is not a direct solution, it's an example of way how to solve this stuff